# solaris zlogin run command from nosuperuser

Tags: solaris, csh, solaris-10

i want execute long running command from global zone in csh shell in zlogin non-interactive mode

```
zlogin zone1 su - adm   /usr/bin/stop_c &  
Warning: no access to tty; thus no job control in this shell...
Oracle Corporation      SunOS 5.10      Generic Patch   January 2005
Badly placed ()'s
logout
```

Try this but its not helps me

```
zlogin zone1 su - adm  /usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/stop_c  
Warning: no access to tty; thus no job control in this shell...
Oracle Corporation      SunOS 5.10      Generic Patch   January 2005
^?ELF^A^B^A^B^B^A^A^G≤4: Command not found
Variable syntax
logout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the supported way to run a command as a different user with zlogin:

```
zlogin -l adm zone1 /usr/bin/stop_c &
```